Will we have dunya things like luxury cars, private jets, yacths, tv, video games etc. in Jannah
Or will we only have brand new things in Jannah?

Sure, ... but only if you want, ... and why you might ever want such things in Heaven?
Luxury car and private jets for transportation? You could probably easily be anywhere allowed to you anytime you wish? Also luxury is useless if limited resources which makes luxury things valuable in Dunya will end in Heaven, so you'll have a Ferrari that will never make you special in eyes of the others, and you yourself being totally satisfied never need the others to think you are special for anything other than being yourself.

Thats not true. People dont only want luxury things to show off. Were in the world did you get that idea, lmao?

@HewaMamyounis, no offense intended, the idea is not so strange to me but anyway that's not the only aspect of this answer as well, as already said "Luxury car and private jets for transportation?". You may elaborate why one might like to have some, and receive a more proper answer accordingly.

Well because they look great, they drive fast, and they are comfortable to sit in.

why do you need to drive fast in Heaven if you can immediately be anywhere you want (I don't claim that would be possible for everyone)? why then it is important to be comfortable if the ride is like in the blink of an eye? If the cars and aircrafts are useless things in Heaven, do they still look great, and you may ask to have one?

Also, The Heaven is the best possible (for what degree you will be on, God willing) with the best possible goods ready for you there, like for example best vehicle possible there. So if you asked for something not as good as the one given to you, that would be like Israelites asked Moses to give them  Onion in place of Heavenly food, and Allah gave them but added that they were astray, and those in Heaven will not ask for goods not as good as given to them, not because they cannot, but because they simply are not astray to replace what is good with what is not as good.

وَ إِذْ قُلْتُمْ يَا مُوسَيٰ لَنْ نَصْبِرَ عَلَيٰ طَعَامٍ وَاحِدٍ فَادْعُ لَنَا رَبَّكَ يُخْرِجْ لَنَا مِمَّا تُنْبِتُ الْأَرْضُ مِنْ بَقْلِهَا وَ قِثَّائِهَا وَ فُومِهَا وَ عَدَسِهَا وَ بَصَلِهَا قَالَ أَتَسْتَبْدِلُونَ الَّذِي هُوَ أَدْنَيٰ بِالَّذِي هُوَ خَيْرٌ اهْبِطُوا مِصْرًا فَإِنَّ لَكُمْ مَا سَأَلْتُمْ وَ ضُرِبَتْ عَلَيْهِمُ الذِّلَّةُ وَ الْمَسْكَنَةُ وَ بَاءُوا بِغَضَبٍ مِنَ اللَّهِ ...

And remember ye said: 'O Moses! we cannot endure one kind of food (always); so beseech thy Lord for us to produce for us of what the earth groweth, -its pot-herbs, and cucumbers, Its garlic, lentils, and onions.' He said: 'Will ye exchange the better for the worse? Go ye down to any town, and ye shall find what ye want!' They were covered with humiliation and misery; they drew on themselves the wrath of Allah

as much as I can say, and it is possible that I'm wrong, so only hope that such ideas will help you in your researches and thinking, nothing more ... :)

So whats your point? That we wont have anything in Jannah, because we can automatically do whatever we want? That dosent sound like a paradise at all

@HewaMamyounis, my point is that you can have anything you want in Jannah, but there you will only want what you expect to have a benefit and what you count as beneficial here in Dunya may be counted as not benefical there. If you still liked such things in Jannah, then you will have it, but ONLY if you wish for, and the question is will you still wish such things in Jannah? and my answer is probably NO! The rest of my points are addressing why you probably may not wish such things in Jannah. And of course God knows best, that's my understanding not necessarily the certain truth.

Cool, thanks for your reply
